# Extract a code from the end of a text string that contains Chinese characters in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following situations and want to solve it with 1 formula:

extract `FV3883` and `38` from the string
`originals NMD_R1 女款 白蛇紋FV388338`

extract `VN0A3WM1TUT` and `35` from the string
`Sk8-Hi Reissue CAP 'Glitter Mix/White'VN0A3WM1TUT35`

extract `DC9517-600` and `36.5` from the string:
`1 Mid SE (GS) "Arctic Pink" 櫻花粉 少女粉DC9517-60036.5`

extract `DC9517-600` and `36` from the string
`1 Mid SE (GS) "Arctic Pink" 櫻花粉 少女粉DC9517-60036`

Comment: You asked the same question earlier today, but seem to have deleted that question now. It is unclear why you should delete a question that already had an answer. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Answer (score 1):

As I already answered in your previous question (now deleted), use `regextract()`, like this:

`=regexextract(A2, "([-\w\.]+?)(\d\d(?:\.\d)?)$")`